# JTabbedPane - addTab(title, icon, component) + setTabComponentAt(index, component)

Tags: java, swing

According to this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TabComponentsDemo) to be more detailed [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TabComponentsDemoProject/src/components/TabComponentsDemo.java) I just faced a strange thing...

If I am using method as `addTab(title,icon,component)`  and next want to add additional component with `setTabComponent(count-1,aComponent)` then **aComponent** *replaces* **icon**? I mean in this case tab does not contain icon :(

The effect is something like (see image). But how to add icons on such tabs?

[image]

I am not pretty sure but I guess somehow **aComponent** replaces **icon**... So my question is...
How to have three of them **icon** , **title** and **aComponent** on one tab at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clearly mentioned in the javadoc of [`setTabComponentAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setTabComponentAt%28int,%20java.awt.Component%29) the component you set at the tab will replace the icon and the title

> A non-null value means the component will render the title and JTabbedPane will not render the title and/or icon.

So if you want to have a title, icon and a component on the tab you will have to create your own `Container` containing those 3 items, and set that container using the `setTabComponentAt` method.

Comment: I've tried it already. It doesn't replace title but icon only :( And concerning your last advice could you recommend some snippets ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use `setComponentAt` instead of `setTabComponent`.

You see, `setTabComponent` sets a component in charge of rendering the tabs (I'm guessing that's not what you want).  `setComponentAt` sets the component in the specified tab (I'm guessing this is what you're looking for).

In summary, to add a tab that has a title and icon, and contains a component in the tab body, use:
`addTab(title, icon, component)`

To update (or add) a component to an existing tab, use:
`setComponentAt(index, component)`

To update (or add) an icon to an existing tab, use:
`setIconAt(index, icon)`

To update (or add) a title to an existing tab, use:
`setTitleAt(index, title)`

Comment: No, I want setTabComponent() because  I am interested in tab options... :) I tried but setComponentAt(index,component) is setting component NOT for tab but for jTabbedPane page :S The thing is to add aComponent on tab itself not the jTabbedPane pages %(